# How do I dynamically add new items to dropdown list within this form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element;
    $(".form-element").on("mousedown", function(event){
    element = $('<form><select name="dropdown"><option>Select...</option><option value="new-dropdown">add new...</option><option value="machine3">Machine 3</option><option value="machine4">Machine 4</option></select></form>');
    $("#body-div").append(element);
    });
});
```

The items in the list currently are just there for testing. But I need to be able to click on an add new option and add a new list item.

Comment: Show you html or a fiddle please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/m5mgqp0x/)

It looks like you were trying to dynamically add the entire form, but you only need to add additional `option` elements to your `select` section of your form.

To do this add this HTML

### HTML

```
<input id="text-to-add" type="text" value="Machine 3">
<button id="new-item">Add to dropdown</button>
 <form>
     <select name="dropdown">
         <option>Select...</option>
         <option>Machine 1</option>
         <option>Machine 2</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Then to dynamically add a select element use the [append jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new-item').click(function() {
        console.log($('#text-to-add').val());
        $('select').append( '<option>' + $('#text-to-add').val() + '</option>' );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this did it! I appreciate your expertise. I would upvote, but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

First add a new id for both the select tag and the option tag with the value "new option";

```
element = $('<form>
<select name="dropdown" 
id="sel"><option>Select...</option>
<option value=
"new-dropdown"id="anew">add new...
</option></select></form>');
```

now im assuming that you already have the values for both the value and the text for that option let both of them be x and y respectively;
now add an onClick handler to #anew to append #sel with a new option with value x and text y:

```
z=$('<option value="'+x+'">'+y+'</option>');

$("#anew").onClick(function(){
$("#sel").append(z);
});
```

hope it solves your problem