# How to set the multiple value dynamically using bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I need to set the multiple value dynamically using `bootstrap-select` plugin. I am providing my code below.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-2" style=" width: 13.3%; max-width: 100%;">
<label for="" class="control-label" style="text-align:left;">Menu:</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 well" style="max-height:220px;overflow-y: auto;max-width: 100%;width: 85%;">
<div class="row" id="examMenuGroup"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var options = "<div class='col-md-12'><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' id='allmenu' onclick='checkAll(this.id)'><strong>Select All</strong></label></div></br>";
    var menuArr=[{'menu_name':'Document','id':1},{'menu_name':'Profile','id':2},{'menu_name':'Fee','id':3},{'menu_name':'Communication','id':4}];
    $.each(menuArr,function(i,data)
    { 
        options = options + "<div class='col-md-2'><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='chkmenu[]' data-label='"+data.menu_name+"' id='chkMenu"+data.id+"' value='"+data.menu_name+"'>"+data.menu_name+"</label></div>";
    });
    $('#examMenuGroup').html("");   
    $('#examMenuGroup').append('<%=Encoder.encodeForJS('+options+')%>');
    $('#examMenuGroup').html(options)
    .selectpicker('refresh');
```

Here I have set the `check box` values inside the `bootstrap-select` plugin. But here my requirement is i I need to set the value (`i.e-Document,Profile`) using some click event means when user will click on any button these(`i.e-Document,Profile`) value will select dynamically in the check box.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640069/dynamic-dropdown-options-with-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978806/how-do-i-dynamically-add-new-items-to-dropdown-list-within-this-form-using-jquer) might help!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

To set multiple values, the values need to be passed as an array. To clear the values, pass `""` or `null` as value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add").click(function(){
        var options =  $(this).data("options").split(",");
        $(".selectpicker").val(options).selectpicker("refresh"); //The following one can also be used. It handles refresh internally.
        //$(".selectpicker").selectpicker("val",options);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Idli</option>
  <option>Dosai</option>
  <option>Panayaram</option>
  <option>Poori</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button class="add btn btn-primary" data-options="Idli,Dosai">Add Idli, Dosai</button>
<button class="add btn btn-success" data-options="Poori,Dosai">Add Poori, Dosai</button>
<button class="add btn btn-warning" data-options="Panayaram">Add Panayaram</button>
<button class="add btn btn-info" data-options="Poori">Add Poori</button>
<button class="add btn btn-danger" data-options="">Clear</button>
```

Comment: But here I am using `checkboxes` inside it so as per dynamic value it need to be checked.